# Prevent Gulp Spawn Child Process Error On Exit Due to Grep Not Finding Match

Tags: git, bash, gulp

Using child_process and Gulp 4 with git guppy I'm spawning a child process in a task in response to git hooks that runs a small bash script.

**BASH SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

added_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --diff-filter=AR --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

check_add() {
    echo "$added_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

# Run `npm install` if package.json changed, `bower install` if `bower.json`,
# or `composer install` if composer.json has changed.
check_run package.json "npm install"
check_run bower.json "bower install"
check_run composer.json "composer install"
```

**GULP FILE**

```
gulp.task('post-checkout', gulp.series(
    'post-checkout-install',
    ...
));

gulp.task('post-checkout-install', function () {

    return cp.spawn('sh', ['./bash/git/hooks/post-merge.sh'], {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        cwd: process.cwd()
    });
});
```

I've tested the post-merge script file in /.git/hooks and it works fine, but when performing this through a spawned shell using Gulp it throws this error:

```
$ gulp post-checkout
[19:48:27] Using gulpfile D:\projects\app\gulpfile.js
[19:48:27] Starting 'post-checkout'...
[19:48:27] Starting 'post-checkout-install'...
[19:48:28] 'post-checkout-install' errored after 200 ms
[19:48:28] Error: exited with error code: 1
    at ChildProcess.onexit (D:\projects\app\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:39:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
[19:48:28] 'post-checkout' errored after 208 ms
```

**TESTS**

So I split out the commands to see what might be causing the issue, and from the below snippets it seems to be all due to grep not finding the file or file extension in the diff list, which doesn't cause any issues when run as a gulp hook directly.

```
# No error just running this by itself and it returns the diff list
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD

# Fails I believe since package.json isn't in the diff list, since the
# same command with .js, .css, and .json fails, but .html passes since
# there are only .html files in the diff list
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD | grep "package.json"

# No error and runs npm install since .html files are in the diff list
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD | grep ".html" && eval "npm install"
```

So how do I stop it from exiting with the above error just because the file or file type isn't found in the list?  I tried adding -ef flags to the grep, but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE**

This seems to squash the error that gets thrown.  I'm not sure it is required to exit the process, but added it anyway and invoked the done callback.  That said it still doesn't run properly.

```
gulp.task('post-checkout-install', function (done) {

    return cp.spawn('sh', ['./bash/git/hooks/post-merge.sh'], {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        cwd: process.cwd()
    }).on('exit', function (code) {

        done();

        process.exit(code);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the non-zero exit status of grep to result in a non-zero exit status of `check_run` or `check_add`, then rewrite them as follows:

```
check_run() {
    if echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1"
    then
        eval "$2"
    fi
}

check_add() {
    if echo "$added_files" | grep --quiet "$1"
    then
        eval "$2"
    fi
}
```